# Explode the string value by using the index value in PHP

Tags: php, explode

I have a string that has been concatenated by the rows and columns that has be separated by using the special characters. Below is my code:

```
$strMaterialDetails = '13-"9"Strawberry%*DEALER%*15%*25%*375%*7.500%*7.500%*28.13%*2.000%*2.000%*6.94@^$14-"9" Yellow white Acrylic Long Pile Ext Roller Set%*DISTRIBUTOR%*45%*75%*3375%*2.500%*2.500%*84.38%*5.000%*5.000%*164.53@^$';

$pairs = explode('@^$', $strMaterialDetails);

foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    list($product, $store, $qty, $unit, $total_price, $discount, $discount_percen, $discount_value, $tax, $tax_percen, $tax_val) = explode('%*', $pair);

    echo $store;
}
```

It works fine I have to insert the values into the database if I print the `$store` it will print `DEALERDISTRIBUTOR`

I want to seperate this I don't know how to do. The string here entered is unknown.

Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Please fix your code. The first line is invalid.

Comment: maybe some characters in the research pattern need to be escaped?

Comment: now check the code. i want to separate the rows and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store it in an array?

```
$stores = array();
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    list($product,$store,$qty,$unit,$total_price,$discount,$discount_percen,$discount_value,$tax,$tax_percen,$tax_val) = explode('%*', $pair);    
    $stores[] = $store;
}

print_r($stores); // will contain DEALER at 0th index and DISTRIBUTOR at 1st index
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uIddJR)

Answer (score 1):

Your `DEALERDISTRIBUTOR` is not store in `$store`

actualy you are printing the `$store`  in loop without any space that why it is printing combine.

originaly in first loop `$store=DEALER` then you echo it. and in second loop `$store=DISTRIBUTOR` so it is confustion only.

you can have Two solution for check it.

**Solution : 1**
print a new line after echo the `$store` like this

```
foreach ($pairs as $pair) 
{
       list($product,$store,$qty,$unit,$total_price,$discount,$discount_percen,$discount_value,$tax,$tax_percen,$tax_val) = explode('%*#', $pair);

        echo $store;
        echo "<br/>";

 }
```

**Solution : 2**  save `$store` in array

```
foreach ($pairs as $pair) 
    {
           list($product,$store,$qty,$unit,$total_price,$discount,$discount_percen,$discount_value,$tax,$tax_percen,$tax_val) = explode('%*#', $pair);

           $arr_store[] = $store;

     }
    print_r($arr_store);
```

Comment: the string is in unknown character i cant separate all the string using substr. i want to sepatare  this as rows